# Request image and encode to raw pixel buffer in Node

Tags: node.js, buffer, image-manipulation

I'd like to manipulate an image in Node and push it to S3 without having to save it locally.

I'm using the lwip module right now, which accepts "raw pixel" buffers. My code for getting a buffer is like this.

```
request.get( { url: imageUrl, setEncoding: null }, function ( err, response, body ) {
    if ( err ) 
        reject( new Error( err ) )

    image.buffer = body

    resolve( image )
})
```

But this doesn't seem to be accepted. Is there a way to get this raw pixel data, or another module that supports this type of buffer?

Comment: The lwip documentation says that in case of raw pixel buffer you will need width and height of the image. I'm having this problem right now because since I already have the raw pixel buffer I don't have the dimensions. So you should better convert it to encoded image data instead where you don't need dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

I maintain the [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) Node.js module that accepts many compressed image formats as input and, after an optional resize, can convert these to [raw](https://github.com/lovell/sharp#raw), uncompressed RGB (or RGBA) pixel data in a Buffer. Might this provide what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi Lovell, do you know how I can get the height and width of a raw image buffer so that I can pass it to your constructor?